# ConvertTo-Html from hash table of html content to html document

Tags: powershell

I am trying to display some html encoded information on a document that is generated by a scheduled execution of a powershell script.

The following MVP illustrates my issue:

```
@{ a="<div style=""color:red;"">Hello</div>"; b="Hi"}.GetEnumerator() | Select Key, Value | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File -Encoding utf8 -FilePath C:\Scripts\Test.html
```

Which outputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Key</th><th>Value</th></tr>
<tr><td>a</td><td>&lt;div style=&quot;color:red;&quot;&gt;Hello&lt;/div&gt;</td></tr>
<tr><td>b</td><td>Hi</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Which, when opened, looks like:

[image: Ouptut of command when opened]

But I want my `Hello` to be red, and not to see the escaped html `div` code.

Is there any way to tell `ConvertTo-Html` not to escape my inputs?

Note: This MVP only illustrates the issue I'm facing. I actually have a very complex report that I would like to decorate for easier viewing (color coding, symbol, et al).

This is the report I am trying to configure:
[image: Badly formatted report output]

Comment: It's unclear to me what you expect. Use the parameter `-Fragment` to get only the table.

Comment: My html is being escaped in the output. I want my html to be part of the table in the output if I were to save it to a .html file.

Comment: Well your code does still what **I** expect. See output without `ConvertTo-Html`. I think some of your context is missing.

Comment: I don't want to write the entire table structure (and html file) manually I would like to use `ConvertTo-Html`. There is a more complex scenario but I didn't want to post 50 lines of powershell that have nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet is to provide an easy-to-use tool for converting lists of objects into tabular HTML reports. The input for this conversion is expected to be non-HTML data, and characters that have a special meaning in HTML are automatically escaped. This cannot be turned off.

Unescaped HTML fragments can be inserted into the HTML report via the parameters `-Body`, `-PreContent`, and `-PostContent` before or after tabular data. However, for more complex reports this probably isn't versatile enough. The best approach in situations like that is to generate the individual parts of your report as fragments, e.g.

```
$ps = Get-Process | ConvertTo-Html -PreContext '<p>Process list</p>' -Fragment
```

and then combine all fragments with a here-string:

```
$html = @"
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
${ps}
<hr>
${other_fragment}
...
</body>
</html>
"@
```

As for individual formatting of particular parts of generated fragments: that is not supported. You need to modify the resulting HTML code yourself, either via search&replace (in fragments or the full HTML content) or by parsing and modifying the full HTML content.

Comment: So if I had 7 columns and I want the 5th column to have some html formatting I provide, my only option is to manually generate the html table myself instead of using `ConvertTo-Html`?

Comment: Like I already said: you can use `ConvertTo-Html` to generate the table, but you need to modify the generated code afterwards if you want particular formatting. `ConvertTo-Html` doesn't support that.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. This seems like an oversight in the implementation but I am glad to get confirmation that there's no easy way to handle it. I'll probably generate the HTML myself because search and replace just seems more difficult then it's worth.

Comment: How I overcame this limitation in the past: use the earlier named -fragment switch and cast the output to XML (the fragmented html validates as valid xml). This gives you an easy way to add attributes to your html.

Comment: @bluuf Good point. Might be worth noting, though, that this applies only to a plain fragment (without prepending or appending other elements). If the fragment is modified (like for instance in my first code snippet) you'd need to wrap it an artificial root node (and remove that root node again after making the desired changes).